# image from JSON to Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, resources

The JSON list always contains one of two image names (one.png or two.png). Please explain how to make this image appear in the application (in the project, these two images are already in \ src \ main \ res \ mipmap-hdpi).

Json file looks like this:

`{"Api":[{"Info":"Random text","Img":"one.png","Desc":"Alarm","TimeStamp":1626010201}]}`

project for Kotlin, I'm just starting to learn it.

In php something like that I would have written:

````
$onepng = \sic\home\res\mipmap-hdi\one.png; // path in the project to 'one.png'
$twopng = \sic\home\res\mipmap-hdi\two.png; // path in the project to 'two.png'
$ImgOneTwo = (JSON IMG == one.png) ? $onepng : $twopng;```


In layout:
    ```<ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImgOneTwo"
        android:src="@mipmap/one">
    </ImageView>```
````

Comment: Is your question about parsing JSON or how to use an ImageView? We need to know which specific thing you are stuck on to be able to answer it without simply quoting the complete documentation. Thanks.

Comment: You could also consider tagging your question with `android`. It seems to be really more related to Android than to Kotlin or JSON.

Comment: In php something like that I would have written:
```$onepng = \sic\home\res\mipmap-hdi\one.png; // path in the project to 'one.png'
$twopng = \sic\home\res\mipmap-hdi\two.png; // path in the project to 'two.png'
$ImgOneTwo = (JSON IMG == one.png) ? $onepng : $twopng;```


In layout:
   ``` <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImgOneTwo"
        android:src="@mipmap/one">
    </ImageView>```

Answer (score 1):

You can show the corresponding image after getting the response from the api using if-else statements.
Assuming that you are using retrofit to get the JSONArray, you can do it like this:

```
val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(YourApiInterface::class.java)

    val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getJSONArray()
    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<ApiResponse?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ApiResponse?>,
            response: Response<ApiResponse?>
        ) {
            if (response.body()!!.api[0].Img == "one.png") {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one)
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.two)
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.v("Ret fail", t.message.toString())
        }
    })
```